# How to detect apple watch shake and notify it?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, motion

Do you know how to implement code to detect the motion of apple watch and notify it on the watch and on the iphone?

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides Forehand & backhand swing count detection, SwingWatch: [Device motion sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017286-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demonstrating how to use `CMMotionManager()` and `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:)` to count swings in a health/workout related app with motion manager.